# When is d elided?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

I know that plosive consonants can change in natural Mandarin speech, like intervocalic g is almost always elided, and sometimes k,  but b and p are almost never elided, but when should d be elided?

I found this example of 知道 as zhao/zao, (https://chinesehacks.com/vocabulary/syllable-contractions/),but I'm trying to focus on Beijing Mandarin instead of Taiwanese so I didn't think much of it. However, I then found this page on the Beijing dialect which had the same change (https://pinyin.sogou.com/zimeiti/article/1255).

The often cited example is that 知道 changes to rdao in 不知道 for Beijing speakers, but when should d disappear and remain then? Is it something about dao being unstressed in 知道 but stressed in 不知道? Is it about the combination of zh+d? or i+d?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: (Disclaimer: beginner here). Isn't the first example (zhi dao > zhao) specific to Taiwanese Mandarin and the second example (buzhidao > buRdao) specific to Beijing Mandarin; and those are two different dialects so we can't derive a rule from these examples?

Comment: @范阮煌  The "zhao/zao" example is found in both articles for Taiwan and Beijing dialects

Comment: I don't think it is regular. It just depends on how fast you say, for 'bu zhi dao' is als pronounced as 'burao' in Beijing dialect sometimes.

Comment: I'm afraid 知道 as zhao/zao may not be a suitable example for Beijing Mandarin, (just in my experience), the pronunciation of 知道 as zhao/zao (for Beijing Mandarin) just occurs in the recent ten years beginning as a network slang. It has accepted by young people widely, but may have no relevance about the pronounciation rules. (just in my experience :-)